# why is the difference for area and exponent operator?

Tags: python-3.x

why are there difference between * and **

```
def disk_area(radius):
    return 3.14*(radius**2)
7.065
```

Versus

```
def disk_area(radius):
    return 3.14*radius*radius
7.0649999999999995
```

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is subject to errors due to the nature of the binary representation of floating point numbers. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Exponent operator supports negative, fractional, and complex values:

```py
3 ** -1
5 ** math.sqrt(2)
1j ** (1 + 1j)
```

You're not going to make any of those happen with `*` multiply operators, right?

Comment: but why one version gives 7.065 vs the other gave 7.0649999999999995. Sorry cant get it from your answer

Comment: @Newbie [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5958455) is what you want to read.